# Weblogc - Deploy Jar File

Tags: spring, service, jar, weblogic

Well kind of a crazy question and I may be off my rocker but here it goes.  I have a Java project that is NOT and web application.  It is basically a service that right now is started using the main method and a Spring Application context.

My desire in deploying this service into a Web Logic container is to have all the features that come with such a deployment, mainly JNDI datasources, etc.

So with that said....am I crazy or is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

If the datasources are really all that you want, you can fetch weblogic initial context from a standalone application. Then get the pools from the context..

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>(); 
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory"); 
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http://<host>:<port>"); 
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, <foo>); 
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, <bar>); 
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(env);
```

Comment: Excellent!  I did not know that was possible.  However I did fail to mention that web logic would also automatically start the spring context.  Any suggestions on this one?  Maybe I should just wrap it as a war/ear and call it good?

Comment: @Norge: That, I think, is always the better idea. I've seen this very usage in a serious production environment (read real time banking application) before -actually the whole Weblogic was dedicated to serving a standalone application, go figure- and asked the fellows to convert their application to a war. :P